# If the database is down all controllers fail with a 500 (play 1.2.5) - can I override that behavior?

Tags: playframework

this is what seems to be the behavior in play 1.2.x: If an application has at least one model/entity and therefore relies on JPA, and the database connection (mysql) is failing (timeout or database down) then controller methods fail with a 500 error before even reaching the method code even if the method does not use the database.

This prevents for example to write a database health check controller method, or a method that would be somewhat resilient to database errors.

I have verified this with a simple project. To reproduce:

1. Create a new application
2. Create at least one Model/Entity and define a mysql database connection.
3. Create one simple controller method that just renders text (does not make use of the database) and associated route (let's say /playdbtest)

To test - start the application and:

1. Invoke playdbtest when the database is available (should work)
2. Turn off mysql and invoke playdbtest while the database is down (will fail)
3. Disable/Delete the entity class and restart play / #2 will work

Question: Is there a way to circumvent that behavior or catch the error? An application should not completely fail because its database connection is failing - although its ability to serve the requests will be impaired.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source, I've found that you can use the annotation `@NoTransaction` on your controller methods which don't require a DB connection.

You can customize the error page in `views/errors/500.html`.

Comment: Hey Sam - Thanks! This is a possible workaround for me for the particular healthcheck I want to implement. Unfortunately I will have to rely on something else than JPA most likely to test my database connection, but I think it could work.   On a more generic level though, it seems not right that the application would just error because JPA cannot do its job. As a matter of fact an application should never show a 500 error in my opinion and always be able to recover to a certain extend to show something to the user.

Comment: For example, if the database is not available, the application might still be able to function minimally on cache only - and a customized error page is not an acceptable solution. Hopefully there is way to workaround this.

Comment: You could also customize/replace the play `JPAPlugin` which handles the database connection (and doesn't fail gracefully). But then, you'll have to ask yourself if Play is the right framework for the architecture you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to samuel's answer, you can also catch errors on controllers.

```java
public class Admin extends Application {

@Catch(IllegalStateException.class)
public static void logIllegalState(Throwable throwable) {
    Logger.error("Illegal state %s…", throwable);
}

public static void index() {
    List<User> users = User.findAll();
    if (users.size() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid database - 0 users");
    }
    render(users);
}
}
```

[play! examples](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/controllers)

Comment: Thanks! That would have been a good general solution but, unfortunately, this only seems to work if the exception originates from within the controller method. In this case, the exception happens before we even get in the controller method and it still fails without getting into the @catch handler.